# Gracefully starting/stopping Java apps on Linux

Tags: java, linux, bash, tomcat, ubuntu

I am trying to design a graceful startup/shutdown script (Bash) for a Java app (JAR) that I will be deploying to my Ubuntu 14.04 server. I'm looking for a clean, Linux- and Ubuntu-friendly way of starting the server like so:

```
java -jar myapp.jar <lots off subsequent arguments>
```

And then, in the shutdown script, finding the JAR's PID, issuing a SIGSTOP to allow the app to do a graceful shutdown on its own, and then finally killing the PID when its good and ready.

I looked at how Tomcat handles this with its own `catalina.sh` and was surprised to find it wasn't doing too much other magic under the hood then simply killing a PID.

I was wondering if [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) may be a good candidate for such a use case, and if so, how? Otherwise, what are some other approaches that I might be able to take? Any other Linux/Ubuntu facilities/tools/programs out there that I should consider?

Comment: Generally speaking, the preferred approach for servers generally (including database servers such as MySQL and Postgres) is for the server to open a control socket and then have the script send it commands. For a Java application, this could be a simple line-based custom protocol or a simple HTTP endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @chrylis (+1) - do you have any links that you can share to other Java projects that use this approach?

Comment: Tomcat is sort of unclean. That's why it says look for stale PIDs and kill any processes that are still running.

Comment: Bueller.....bueller....bueller (@chrylis)?